# Clear QGIS plot results window

Tags: qgis, r, qgis-processing

How do you clear old plots from the plots result window in QGIS?

Is there a line of R code that you'd need to run to do so, or is there a means of doing so through the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

I only could do that by quit from qGis.
All results tables and plots are erased.
Sorry, for the lack of code or instructions in gui.